# Python: Function not seen despite clearly being there

Tags: python

Below code has a call to a method called **lago**.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Copyright (c) 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
#

import sys

class InstallTest():
    """Ru Ovirt System Tests"""


    def run_command_checking_exit_code(command):
        """ Runs a command"""
        print("Command is " + str(command))
        print(command.read())
        print(command.close())

    def lago():
        """run the conductor profiles required to install OLVM """
        Log.test_objective('TODO')
        run_command_checking_exit_code('ls -al')
        """
        yum_list = ["epel-release", "centos-release-qemu-ev", "python-devel", "libvirt", "libvirt-devel", "libguestfs-tools", "libguestfs-devel", "gcc", "libffi-devel", "openssl-devel", "qemu-kvm-ev"]
        for yum in yum_list

        ret, msg, tup = self.client.run('/qa/conductor/tests/' + OSSE_OLV_VERSION + '/installer/installerfactory.py -s ' + OSSE_OLV_ENGINE_HOST + ' -t OS_OL7U6_X86_64_PVHVM_30GB -c 10.1.0.10 -o ' + self.log_jobdir_cc +'/vm_install_ol7.6', timeout=1000000)
        if ret:
            self.tc_fail('Creation of OLV Engine VM failed')
        ret, msg, tup = self.client.run('/qa/conductor/tests/' + OSSE_OLV_VERSION + '/installer/installerfactory.py -s ' + OSSE_OLV_ENGINE_HOST +' -p ovirt-engine -c 10.1.0.10 -o ' + self.log_jobdir_cc + '/engine_deploy', timeout=1000000)
        if ret:
            self.tc_fail('Install of OLV Engine Host failed')
        self.tc_pass('OLV Engine Host installed')
        """

    def main():
        lago()

    main()
```

However, it is shown to not exist in the output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rafranci/Downloads/ovirt_st_setup.py", line 20, in <module>
    class InstallTest():
  File "C:/Users/rafranci/Downloads/ovirt_st_setup.py", line 65, in InstallTest
    main()
  File "C:/Users/rafranci/Downloads/ovirt_st_setup.py", line 63, in main
    lago()
NameError: name 'lago' is not defined
```

As far as I can see, there is no reason for this - ideas?

Comment: the indent of the code is very suspicious.

Comment: did you mean for the main() to be inside the class InstallTest

Comment: You appear to have put your functions inside an unnecessary class, without understanding how to write class methods. If you delete the class and correspondingly unindent your functions, they will be callable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to instantiate class to call its method.

```
def main():
   InstallTest().lago()
```

or

```
def main():
   install_test = InstallTest()
   install_test.lago()
```

This will work only if you are adding `self` parameter in your class.

```
def lago(self):
    """run the conductor profiles required to install OLVM """
    Log.test_objective('TODO')
    run_command_checking_exit_code('ls -al')
```

Also, I don't understand why you needed class for this. If you don't have any reason you can just remove the class and then your previous code will work fine as suggested in the comments.

Comment: don't necessarily have to initiate it, e.g. `InstallTest.lago()`

Comment: You mean defining the method as a `staticmethod` or `classmethod`?

Comment: @PratikGandhi The `lago` method as written does not have a `self` parameter, so it _cannot_ be called as an instance method.

Comment: You are right! didn't noticed that. updating the answer

Answer (score 1):

Check the changes in code:

```
class InstallTest():
    """Ru Ovirt System Tests"""


    def run_command_checking_exit_code(command):
        """ Runs a command"""
        print("Command is " + str(command))
        print(command.read())
        print(command.close())

    def lago(self):
        """run the conductor profiles required to install OLVM """
        #Log.test_objective('TODO')
        #run_command_checking_exit_code('ls -al')
        """
        yum_list = ["epel-release", "centos-release-qemu-ev", "python-devel", "libvirt", "libvirt-devel", "libguestfs-tools", "libguestfs-devel", "gcc", "libffi-devel", "openssl-devel", "qemu-kvm-ev"]
        for yum in yum_list

        ret, msg, tup = self.client.run('/qa/conductor/tests/' + OSSE_OLV_VERSION + '/installer/installerfactory.py -s ' + OSSE_OLV_ENGINE_HOST + ' -t OS_OL7U6_X86_64_PVHVM_30GB -c 10.1.0.10 -o ' + self.log_jobdir_cc +'/vm_install_ol7.6', timeout=1000000)
        if ret:
            self.tc_fail('Creation of OLV Engine VM failed')
        ret, msg, tup = self.client.run('/qa/conductor/tests/' + OSSE_OLV_VERSION + '/installer/installerfactory.py -s ' + OSSE_OLV_ENGINE_HOST +' -p ovirt-engine -c 10.1.0.10 -o ' + self.log_jobdir_cc + '/engine_deploy', timeout=1000000)
        if ret:
            self.tc_fail('Install of OLV Engine Host failed')
        self.tc_pass('OLV Engine Host installed')
        """

    def main(self):
        self.lago()

    def __init__(self):
        self.main()
InstallTest()
```